# SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tblmembers'

Tags: php, mysql

I have edited all the privileges for the user `'root'@'localhost` for table `tblmembers`

but still,

`SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tblmembers'`

What is the problem? I'm looking for a solution for almost two days, and still I cant find answers.

Here is my code for selection:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','add');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Cannot connect to database:' . mysqli_connect_errno();
}
$order = "SELECT firstName,lastName,ID FROM add.tblmembers";
$result = mysql_query($order);
if($result === false)
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
echo "<table>";     
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ID'];
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: as from error  ''@'localhost' means that you are trying to connect with empty username ... that is strange because your mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','add'); is ok. you sould do this first " grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhist' identified by 'your password here' ".

Comment: where should i put those codes?

Comment: Now I got it! haha I just make mysqli_connect to mysql_connect. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Glad you're getting somewhere -- but the mysql library has been depreciated; it's advised to use PDO or mysqli instead. Learn more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli